# Installed Ubuntu (on its own partition, Windos 8 machine) and lost both boot options in BIOS

Tags: boot-loader, uefi

[image][image]I partitioned the unit in Windows first, and after I disabled Windows in BIOS because it wasn't allowing the boot CD to load. 
After the installation, the option to enable Windows and the option to enable Ubuntu in BIOS were no longer there.
How do I get them to function?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to as "Windows in BIOS"? Do you mean you disabled booting from hard disk in the BIOS so that it would boot from DVD? When you're in ubuntu what's the output of `fdisk -l` ran from the command line?

Comment: @JoelDavis It gives me a message saying that the disk is not valid and doesn't load anything. In BIOS I only have Realtek (network) and the DVD option. I did make a windows recovery USB, which I don't know how to execute.

Comment: @JoelDavis With UEFI, each individual operating system can be listed as a boot option in the BIOS. A Windows 8 machine is surely using UEFI.